# Specific iteration using for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an ajax call which returns same data

```
obj[0],obj[1],obj[2],obj[3],obj[4],obj[5],obj[6],obj[7],obj[8],obj[9],obj[10],obj[11]....
```

So i want to take only  `obj[0]-obj[3] and obj[4]-obj[7] and obj[8]-obj[11]...`

```
var iterate=0;

for(i=0 ;i<obj.length ; i++)
 {
 alert(obj[iterate].mydata);

 iterate=iterate+3;

 }
```

here the issue is , it iterates each time so i cant get valjue of  obj[4]  after obj[3] 
Any idea ?

Comment: Is `obj` supposed to be an array or what? Are you trying to split an array into chunks? I don't see what the difference would be between `obj[0]-obj[3] and obj[4]-obj[7]` and just `obj[0]-obj[7]`. Please provide a **concrete** example of the input and output you (want to) get. The better you describe your problem, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: You mean you want to slice your array into slices of length 4 ?

Comment: var obj = data.d ;  yes it is an array.

Comment: and what to do with the slices?

Comment: @dystroy  i want to iterate the one i displayed . you know when you use for loop and you are doing iterate = iterate+4 so it increase the value 4

Comment: Uhm so why don't you just do 2 for loops? Btw knowing what you have in the array would help too.. cause I was getting idea that you wanted something else if there were numbers for example..

Comment: i edited it . please take a look at it

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Like you are hiding something behind your problem but still want to get it solved.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp  there is on hiding :S . it is all about it .

Comment: Like I said, it's not clear. `I want to take only ...` only what? obj[0] _minus_ obj[3]? Or the sum of obj[0] to obj[3]? You're talking in rebuses. You may also want to slice the original array into smaller arrays, etc. The point is, you _have to_ explain your problem **and expected solution** in a way so we understand it.

Comment: there is no minus  i want to take obj[0] obj[3] obj[4] obj[7]...

Comment: Can someone who didn't understand question at first or still don't understand so decrease the reputation, please increase the reputation . this is very logical question and it is very useful for you all to gain experience

Comment: If you expect upvotes, you have to at least improve the description of the problem and provide a proper example (as we already explained repeatedly). I really doubt that another user could identify if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continously splicing the array would be easier:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var slices = [];

while( array.length > 0 )
  slices.push( array.splice(0,3) );

console.log( slices );
```

Comment: But also a lot more expensive. You are creating a new array (the deleted elements) and reposition the existing elements in the array. Changing this code to `.slice` would only be a small step.

Comment: @FelixKling would 

    `for(i=0; i<array.length-1; i++) array.unshift( array.splice(i,3) );`

be any less expensive?

Answer (score 0):

The following code takes three elements at each interation:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a += 3) {
    // On the last iteration, array[a+1] and array[a+2]
    // will be undefined, because array is of length 10,
    // and 10 isn't divisible by 3 without a remainder.
    console.log(array[a], array[a+1], array[a+2]);
}
```

Also, in your question you're using `i` and `iterate` interchangeably in your code.

Comment: Hard to get rep when ppl like you type 20 seconds faster :D

Comment: Actually the question was asked 10 minutes ago ;)

Comment: @Ms. Nobody: answer questions for [forth] or [typo3] :-) there is relaxing silence :-)

Comment: Yeah but it was specified to level where I could finally know what does the OP want about a minute ago :D

Answer (score 0):

I think a nested loop will help you. Like this:

```
for(i=0 ;i<obj.length ; i+=4) {  // << step must be 4, not 3

   for (j=0; (j<=3) && (i+j < obj.length); j++) {
      alert(obj[i + j].mydata); // << here you take 0-3, 4-7 etc.
   }

}
```

EDIT: termination in outer loop corrected

Comment: This will break once `iterate > obj.length - 4`, which will happen after `obj.length / 4` iterations (I think).

Comment: I've improved the termination and the usage of counters. Thank you for your hint :-)

Comment: this will resolve the issue , Thanks for your cooperation guys . @FelixKling and peter_the_oak

Comment: Glad to help :-) Plz consider marking the correct answer as it gives quick orientation for other readers.